# What's going on with my 'if' comparison in bash?

Tags: bash, comparison

bash input:

```
if [[ 167 > 10800 ]]
then
    echo "I can't compare"
fi
```

bash output:

```
I can't compare
```

I guess the question is pretty obvious...

Comment: I know the operator is -gt and -lt for [ and ]. I am not sure what [[ and ]] is.

Comment: @bill [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: @slhck: Neither of them works, actually.

Comment: @Mehrdad Neither of what?

Comment: @slhck: Single or double brackets.

Comment: Ah well Matt's got it figured out anyway :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote from the `bash(1)` manual page:

> When used with [[, the < and > operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.

So 167 is indeed greater than 10800 as 6 is a greater ASCII character than 0.

Comment: OOOOHHHH *facemonitor* +1

Answer (score 8):

The `>` character doesn't work for the type of comparison you want. You have to use `-gt`:

```
if [[ 167 -gt 10800 ]]
then
    echo "I can't compare"
fi
```

And if you want to do a less-than comparison, you need to do `-lt`. To see what other options you need to do for comparison, look at the [`test` manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test).

Comment: -1 I [beg to differ](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test/index.html).

Comment: @Mehrdad: edited.

Comment: Interesting, +1...

Answer (score 6):

Use curved brackets for a true numeric comparison

```
if (( 167 > 10800 ))
then
    echo "I can't compare"
fi
```

Good summary here: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Numeric_comparison